# Error deploying to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

This is the error I get in the logs when deploying a RUBY app.

ERROR

> Finished Step #1 Step #1: The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install
>   --deployment --without="development test" && rbenv rehash' returned a non-zero code: 18

Comment: Can you provide more information? App Engine standard or flexible? app.yaml? other files? deployment command?

Answer (score 0):

Going off of the little info you provided and a similar issue I encountered, I'm thinking you were deploying a Rails app in a flex environment. Check out how it decides which Ruby version to use: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/runtime. It may help to create a `.ruby-version` file in your app's root directory as specified. In my case, I specified the wrong version in my `.ruby-version` file: it didn't match up with the version in my `Gemfile`, so it gave me this error message:

```
Step #1: Step 14/17 : RUN bundle install --deployment --without="development test" && rbenv rehash
Step #1:  ---> Running in <some random hash>
Step #1: Your Ruby version is 2.4.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.5
Step #1: The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install --deployment --without="development test" && rbenv rehash' returned a non-zero code: 18
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try bundle update. It's working for me